# table creating using span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create one table using the `<span>` and `<div>` concept.

But the table is not coming together properly. I couldn't find where the issue is. Please tell me what the problem is. I have to produce 4 to 5 lines in a same row.

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style>
            .line1
            { 
               background-color:#AAAAAA;
               height: 150px;
               width: 1px;
               display: block;
            } 
            .line2
            { 
               background-color:#CE5611;
               height: 150px;
               width: 1px;
               display: block;
               margin-left: 121px;
            } 
        </style>
    </HEAD>    
    <body>
        <div id="a1" style='padding-left: 14px;width: 100px;'>
            <span>h1</span>
            <span class="line1"></span>
            <span>h2</span>
            <span class="line2"></span>
            <span>h3</span>
            <span class="line1"></span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. What do you mean "create one table using span and div concept"? Why not use tables? 2. Please accept some answers to your previous questions. It will make people much more likely to want to help you.

Comment: please clear your code / use the code box

Comment: Would a `table` not be more suitable?

Comment: i am trying to create table format using span. as per my assignment standards, i shouldn't use <tr>,<td>. its not exactly table. one text after that one vertical line like that it should come...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead this way of going :

```
<div id="a1" style='padding-left: 14px;width: 100px;'>
                <span>h1</span>
                <span class="line1"></span>
                <span>h2</span>
                <span class="line2"></span>
                <span>h3</span>
                <span class="line1"></span>
</div>
```

do

```
#wrapper .content{
  float:left
  width:100px;
  padding:.5em;
}

#wrapper .content span{
 font-weight:bold;
}


<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="content"><span>line 1</span></div>
  <div class="content"><span>line 2</span></div>
  <div class="content"><span>line 3</span></div>
</div>
```

you got the idea ..

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want the classed spans to have `display: block`? That forces each one onto a seperate line. Functionally, `<span style="display: block">` is kinda the same thing as `<div>` (and `<div style="display: inline">` is kinda the same thing as `<span>`).

You're probably looking for `display: inline-block`. That gives you the ability to block attributes (height, width) like you are, but still leave it moving around within the surrounding contents. Another alternative is to use `display: table-cell`. There's a chart of `display` support [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html).

Comment: thanks for quick response. It is working with "inline-block". but "table-cell" is not working.

Comment: With table-cell, some browsers require you to have parent containers with display: table, and display: table-row.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `li` and `span` tags instead of `div` and `span`. It makes manipulation much easier. With li as `block` and span `inline-block`.